# Fragment BaseAdapter returns a NullPointerException

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

My app consists of two `Fragments` that need to get information from the `MainActivity`. In the `MainActivity` the data is loaded and put into `ArrayLists`, then it should be presented in the first `Fragment`. So I created a method that passes the `ArrayLists` to the first `Fragment`.

The issue I came across is that I get a `NullPointerException` on the `mContactsAdapter = new SimpleAdapter(...)` line in my `Fragment` class. But I don't understand why that is, since I set up the `Adapter` in the `onCreateView` method. Is it set up a wrong way?

My MainActivity:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> contactList;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        contactList = new ArrayList<>();

    }

    public void FillAndPresent() {

        /***
         * fill ArrayLists
         * ...
         */

        CallsFragment fragment = new CallsFragment();
        ((CallsFragment) fragment).show(contactList);

    }

}
```

My Fragment class:

```
public class CallsFragment extends Fragment{

    private BaseAdapter mContactsAdapter;
    private final List<HashMap<String, String>> mContactsListItems = new ArrayList<>();

    public CallsFragment() {

    }


    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_calls, container, false);


        ((ListView) view.findViewById(R.id.list))
                .setAdapter(mContactsAdapter);

        return view;
    }


    public void show(ArrayList c){

        mContactsAdapter = new SimpleAdapter(
                getActivity(), mContactsListItems,
                R.layout.list_item, new String[]{"price", "brand",
                "dist"}, new int[]{R.id.price,
                R.id.brand, R.id.dist});

        mContactsListItems.addAll(c);
        mContactsAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

        ((ListView) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.list))
                .setAdapter(mContactsAdapter);
    }

}
```

Comment: What does the Exception message say (except NullPointerException)?

Comment: `java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.Object android.content.Context.getSystemService(java.lang.String)' on a null object reference
        at android.widget.SimpleAdapter.<init>(SimpleAdapter.java:93)` and then the reference to the mentioned line

Comment: This is happening because the `Fragment` is not yet attached to the `Activity`, so `getActivity()` returns null. See the documentation for information on the [Fragment lifecycle](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments)

Answer (score 0):

As @0x0nosugar said

> This is happening because the Fragment is not yet attached to the Activity"

try this

```
CallsFragment fragment = new CallsFragment();
fragment.show(contactList);
FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.mainActivity,fragment);
// >> here you replace the main activity layout with your fragment by put the id of it.

fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack(null);
fragmentTransaction.commit();
```

read more about fragment [here](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments)

Comment: I guess that should be used in the MainActivity to call the Fragment, shouldn't it? I tried it like this, but still receive the same error

Comment: Do you get the same error or other error?
yes the fragment must must be attached to an activity, anyway edit your question with the suggested answer by me

Comment: Yeah, I'm getting the same error, but I read that it's kind of different to handle if a ViewPager is used, which I'm using

Comment: I adapted my Code now, so I could use your code suggestion and replace the fragment, but I still get the exact same error returned